# How do I make my form on Wix (built with Wix code) autocomplete enabled?

Tags: javascript, velo

I created a form on my website using Wix Code and I want browsers to help users fill it with autocomplete (first name, last name, email, etc...). 
Currently, the browser does not recognize the fields as a form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BY default autocomplete is enable in any wix user element.
drag and drop the input element
set the input type as email, password, or number from the option
change the place holder to first name, last name , city or state
so, that the browser can detect the field
that's it